# stored procedure is not inserting values in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedue which first `update`'s the values in `UserSignUp` table and then `insert`'s in `UserKeyPoints` table but my procedure is not executing.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc_getActivationCode] @ActivationCode VARCHAR(1000)=''
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT ActivationCode
                FROM   UserSignUp
                WHERE  ActivationCode = @ActivationCode
                       AND Activate = 'False')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @UserId INT

            SET @userid= (SELECT AutoID
                          FROM   UserSignUp
                          WHERE  ActivationCode = @ActivationCode)

            UPDATE UserSignUp
            SET    Activate = 'Confirm Code'
            WHERE  ActivationCode = @ActivationCode

            INSERT INTO UserKeyPoints
                        (KeyPoints,
                         UserId)
            VALUES      (500,
                         @userid)

            SELECT 1
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 2
        END
  END
```

Here's the c# code where i am executing my stored procedure.

```
if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
{
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["token"];
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getActivationCode1", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", Request.QueryString["token"].ToString());
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        //Label1.Text = "You are confirmed successfully. Please Click here for Login: ";
        SendEmail objMail = new SendEmail();

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You are already confirmed.";
    }
}
```

When I am executing this code it runs the procedure  without `insert` and `update` and on my `.aspx` page i get the output of `Label1` i.e. `You are already confirmed.`

Can anybody guide me that where am i going wrong with this?

Comment: Your SP have some concurrency issues.

Comment: Regarding the above you can replace the whole `IF EXIST5` stuff and just do the update anyway and use the `OUTPUT` clause to insert the desired values into `UserKeyPoints` directly. Then check `@@ROWCOUNT` to know what value to return. So basically the stored proc then becomes two statements and it fixes the concurrency issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok. This would me much much better. Thanks. Lets R&D this technique.

Comment: @MartinSmith as I have solved my problem but I am glad that i found the alternative approach. Will try to keep i mind the concurrency issues from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem that I can see is the missing [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to StoredProcedure.
This is fundamental to allow the framework code correctly interpret your string.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getActivationCode1", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

As explained in the comment below from [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith), the reason for the failure of the call is that without the CommandType correctly set the parameter is not passed to the storedprocedure but the procedure itself is executed with the default value for the `@ActivationCode` parameter

Then I would write the call to the stored procedure using an ExecuteScalar instead of the use of an SqlDataAdapter to just return a single row with a single column in a datatable

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getActivationCode1", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", Request.QueryString["token"].ToString());
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
    int resultValue = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    if (resultValue == 1)
        SendEmail objMail = new SendEmail();
    else
        Label1.Text = "You are already confirmed.";
}
```

Comment: Yes. the missing command type means that the stored proc still gets executed (a batch consisting of the single word `proc_getActivationCode1` will be treated as a procedure call) but the param is never passed into it.

Comment: I was sure that this causes the misinterpretation of the commandtext and thus no execution of the procedure, but I can be wrong, do you have a reference to add to the answer?

Comment: `EXEC` is optional for the first call in a batch. If you just run the text `sp_help` for example on its own this is treated as a procedure call. Same will happen for `proc_getActivationCode1`

Comment: Oh well, this site is fantastic, never stops to teach something new and change your untested beliefs. You are right of course, just tested the sp_help tip and it works also without the CommandType set. Don't you mind if I complete the answer with your comment?

Comment: @Steve no change in the result but yes not writing `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` really is very silly mistake I did thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Could it be a problem with VARCHAR vs NVARCHAR? What happen if you try to build the parameter with an exact datatype instead of AddWithValue?

Comment: @Steve yeah exactly, that was it!

Comment: Well, good, could you explain what have you changed? I wish to complete the answer for future readers.

Comment: @Steve I removed the `IF EXIST` part in my stored procedure, and updated my code with your improved code.
There is no need to update as everything id did is already in your answer. :)

Comment: @Steve One more thing i too agree that this site never stops teaching something new. You always get more and more to learn from here!